# Tensorboard only showing dots, line not showing

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I am using tensorboard through pytorch and have created a scaler which shows accuracy, loss, and validation accuracy.  When I open the graph it only shows dot and dosen't show a line connecting these dots.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
tb = SummaryWriter(comment=f'-{epoch}')

tb.add_scalar("Accuracy", float(correct/len(train_tensor)*100), epoch)
tb.add_scalar("Loss", loss, epoch)
tb.add_scalar("ValiAccuracy", float(correct/len(train_tensor)*100), epoch)
tb.close()
```

What is leading tensorboard to not show these lines?
[image: Here is what tensorboard looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always creating a new directory with your "comment" (depends on your epoch) in the definition of the SummaryWriter. Each subdirectory will be treated as a different experiment in the tensorboard. Thats why they have different colors and only show dots instead of a connected line.

You can try to define your SummaryWriter without a comment:

```
tb = SummaryWriter()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. One thing to add is that I also kept on redefining my summary writer in my epoch loop which also was another reason why my program was not working before.